# How to fix 'trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given' In Router.php line 560:?

Tags: php, laravel, web

> After 'php artisan make:controller Admin/DashboardController', I included code below (Controllers/Admin/DashboardController).
>
> DashboardController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    //Dashboard
    public function dashboard(){
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }
}
```

> In web.php:

```
Route::get(['prefix'=>'admin', 'namespace'=>'Admin', 'middleware'=> ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@dashboard')->name(admin.index);
});
```

> In views/admin/dashboard.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app)

@section('content')
    <h1>Admin test</h1>
@endsection
```

Comment: none of the code snippets refer to the problematic page `router.php`

Comment: it should be `->name('admin.index')`

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whereas the other answers and comments are right `admin.index` should be `'admin.index'`, the issue here is because you have a `get()` route inside another `get()` route.

If you want to nest routes like this you should use [`Route::group(...)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-groups) (not `get()`):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@dashboard')->name('admin.index');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your route name is not a string, so try this:

```
Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@dashboard')->name('index');
```

You will again access it as `route('admin.index')`